# Bash - Bind command not working with alt key combination

Tags: bash, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm using the native `bind` command from bash, but it seems that it doesn't work with alt keys combination:

```
bind "M-q:echo 'hello'"
```

tried the key code version as well:

```
bind "^[q:echo 'hello'"
```

This one being found using the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> key and then typing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>.

I'm aware of other alternatives such as `sxhkd`, using other shells with better keys binding support etc, but I would prefer using bash for this aswell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it seems i managed to find the answer:

`bind '"\eq":"echo 'foobar'"'`

where `\e` is the keycode for Alt/M, and thus do what the post described...

This only post the command and do not directly execute it, though if one want that, there only need to add `\n` at the end, like so:

`bind '"\eq":"echo 'foobar'\n"'`

Seems like the recommended way to find the keycode (which is done by using the `Ctrl+V` combination) didn't work in this instance and gave the wrong keycode. Though, using `bind -p` to see existing keybinding is a good way to figure things out.